# In "that pig is as solid as they come" what does "they come" mean?

Tags: meaning

I read this sentence in Charlotte's Web:

> That pig is as solid as they come.

Can somebody explain what "they come" means, who does *they* refer to?

Comment: I don't see why the meaning is not immediately apparent to you. From the shores of Indonesia, to the streets of Shanghai, to the boulevards of Paris - people know the meaning of "solid". e.g., I have a solid offer from the client. This is "as good as gets", they are the best. Today is as hot as it gets in Shanghai - it is among the hottest days of the summer here.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning our sister site for [ell.SE] here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This meaning of "come" is "to be available, produced, offered, etc" as seen in meaning 8 of [this definition](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/come)

For example

```
Cars are available in a range of sizes.
  Cars come in a range of sizes.
    That car is as big as they come.

Pigs are available in a range of solidities.
  Pigs come in a range of solidities.
    That pig is as solid as they come.
```

Answer (score 1):

"They" refers to pigs, in this case, or whatever it is the person is talking about.  The phrase means that the given pig ("that pig") is as good ("as solid") as possible ("as they come").

Comment: So does the "come" mean "could be"? The sentence can be written as "That pig is as solid as pigs could be?"

Comment: Sure, although I would say "can be."

Comment: Solid is in the meaning of "a solid citizen".
_That pig is as reliable, sensible and upstanding as any reliable, sensible and upstanding pigs I know_.

Comment: I think that it's not quite meant to mean "as they can be" but "as are available from wherever they're made" which means they are "as you can get".  The difference being that I might complain about the quality of something (which means I think they could be better) but I might be told, "That's as good as they come." Then I could start a company to make better ones and advertise them as "as good as they come"

Answer (score 1):

Read: “That pig is as solid as *pigs* come.”

Comment: Right on. Which you could also read as: "That pig is as solid as a pig can be."

Answer (score 0):

When the author refers to "Solid" pig, he means

**characterized by good substantial quality**

When we say **"as solid as they come"**, it is akin to **"as good as it gets."** Literally it would mean that this pig is comparable to best of pigs.This is "as solid as they come",would literally mean **this is the best Nature can provide.**

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer the question, the semantic meaning of "they" is the set of all pigs. The meaning of the sentence is that compared against all pigs, Wilbur is as solid as any of them.